# Can a J-1 postdoc start a remote job abroad?

Tags: united-states, european-union, visa

I am a postdoc in a US university on a J-1 visa.
I have found a tenure-track faculty position in Europe, and would like to start there soon.

However, it's not clear if I will be able to travel in time, and given that the coming semester will be taught remotely, I want to start while staying here.

> Is it legal for a J-1 postdoc to have another job (with a non-US university)?

That is, I am hoping to be a part-time postdoc for several months and then move.
(I will be agreeing with my host on a reduced salary as I will be part time teaching in the other job).

---

Would it affect my spouse's J-2 work permit?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I will bet that your university's international scholars office does.

Comment: They haven't responded in over a week now :(. @NateEldredge

Comment: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely. [This page from Dept. of State](https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/current/adjustments-and-extensions/) discusses adjustments such as change of category, transfer, and among the things noted is that unauthorized employment is grounds for termination. [The regulation governing employment](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e6002a3051c28e0588b5819cb6b96547&mc=true&node=se22.1.62_116&rgn=div8) says that

> (a) An exchange visitor may receive compensation from the sponsor or
> the sponsor's appropriate designee, such as the host organization,
> when employment activities are part of the exchange visitor's program.
>
> (b) An exchange visitor who engages in unauthorized employment shall
> be deemed to be in violation of his or her program status and is
> subject to termination as a participant in an exchange visitor
> program.

That would preclude taking another job, other than the current postdoc.

Comment: It's not clear that (b) is talking about employment that does not need an authorization by the US government (such as a job abroad, that the OP is asking about).

Comment: It is clear that any employment requires authorization, the question is who can give such authorization. The regulation doesn't define a category of "employments needing no authorization".

Comment: slow down, please.  I don't think the US government claims that you need an authorization from the US govt to work abroad if you already have an authorization to work in the US.  I think (b) is there to say that you would lose your visa if you take an extra off-books job in the US and get caught.

Comment: as a thought experiment, consider what would it mean if you are right and the US does require one to get an authorization from the US govt to work abroad for anyone who has an authorization to work in the US.  If there are jobs which are "unauthorized", there must also be jobs which are authorized, right?  Otherwise, all jobs neither authorized nor unauthorized.  Is there a formal way to seek such an authorization for a J-1 visa holder?  if not, then the regulation is silent on whether such a job is authorized.

Comment: The regulation does not explain this, but you apply to the/a sponsoring entity. You could switch universities (or other employers) in the US; you could switch departments within an institution. But U. Oslo cannot be the sponsor for a US J-1 visa. It's required under §62.5(c)(8)(i) that the entity be a "US person".

Comment: it also doesn't say that one must abandon all positions in the domicile country. if one were to spend (let's say) U. Oslo sabbatical at a US university, one would be sponsored by a US university to work in the US for that US university while simultaneously remaining in employment of a foreign one. what you say amounts to arguing that this regulation applies to employment which does not require a US authorization. so such employment (that does not require a US authorization) may be "unauthorized" from the viewpoint of the US regulation.